# How to run Repeated Measures to find difference between gender (without change of condition)?

Tags: statistical-significance, repeated-measures, experiment-design, manova

**I would like to test for the difference of measures between genders. Repeated measures were carried out. What test would you suggest is best for this and what would be the degrees of freedom considering:**

> > > 1. there is no change in conditions
> > > 2. uneven group size (females=6 and males=4)
> > > 3. missing repeated measures (8 levels) between 3 subjects**

### The Data Explained

There are *6 females* and *4 males* = **10 subjects in total**

*28 Repeated measures* (events or levels) per person with **no** change in condition except time.

> 28 x 10 subjects = **280 repeated measures (rm)**

At each level there should be:

> *19 ordinal independent variables* **(IV)**
>
> > **from** which
>
> *7 continuous dependent variables* **(DV)** are recorded
>
> > 19 (IV) x 7 (DV) =  133 measures (one level per subject)
> > 133 x 28 rm per subject = 3724 measures (all levels per subject)
> > 3724 x 10 subjects  = 37240 total measures of data

#### Missing data (from the expected totals as described above)

> *8 levels* of data between *3 subjects* are missing:
>
> > **2 events** (rm) missing for **2 males** 
> > **4 events** (rm) missing for **1 female**
> > 280 rm - 8 rm  = **272 rm in total**
> > 8 missing rm x 133 measures per rm = **1064 total measures missing** 
> > 37240 - 1064 = **36176 total measures of data**

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks for reviewing. I have edited the question keeping it purely statistical and your expertise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @PeterFlom Thanks for reviewing. I have edited the question keeping it purely statistical and your expertise would be greatly appreciated.